# Error: Cannot access protected member 

Tags: mobile

I am getting following error when I access SP site using Android Browser. I need to know what is the exact cause of this error and how to solve it.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: Compilation Error]

Comment: Have you customized that page?

Comment: No! When I input the URL of my SP Site from an Android mobile, the above error shows up. Just to add... SP site does not even let me log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue as given below:

As we are using FBA customization authentication and on top of that we are using custom login page which were causing the issue.

From mbllogin.aspx, removed lines which are causing errors and that has fixed the issue.